# How to send file as response

Tags: rest, go

I am building a REST application with an use case in which client sends a GET request with some params and on server side the API process it and creates a tar file. At the end it should send this tar file to client, like auto download based on a query. Any help here?
I am stuck after creation of tar file, not sure how can I send this file to client (like auto download)

Sample code to emulate my question

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", someHandle)

    port := ":8080"
    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

 }

func someHandle(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
     ...
     ... 
     some code 
     ...
     
     file, err := createFile(filePath)
     ...
     //Now I have to send this file as response, any thoughts?
}
```

Comment: If `file` in `io.Writer`, then `io.Copy(res, file)`.  What is the type of `file`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [http.ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) is what you are looking for.

Here is a working example:

```
package main

    import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
    )
    
    type Server struct {
        listenPort string
    }
    
    func (s *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        router := http.NewServeMux()
    
        router.HandleFunc("/download", s.downloadHandler)
        router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    
    func (s *Server) downloadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w,r, "file.tar.xz")
    }
    
    func main(){
        s := &Server{listenPort: ":8080"}
    
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(s.listenPort, s); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not listen on port %s: %v", s.listenPort, err)
        }
    }
```